# Why do I get a cross-domain error only in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, cors, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have the following code in test.js:

```
var symbol = "GOOG";
var Url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/' + symbol + '/quote?filter=symbol,companyName,open,close,high,low,change,changePercent';
$.ajax({
    url: Url,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error received:  " + error)
        console.log(`Error ${error}`)
    }
})
```

It works beautifully, returning no errors and all the JSON I desired.  BUT ... if I put this within a callback, for instance, the following code, I get a Cross-domain error.  Why would this happen?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        const symbol = document.getElementById('symbol').value;
        var Url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/' + symbol + '/quote?filter=symbol,companyName,open,close,high,low,change,changePercent';

        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error received:  " + error)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML with id='symbol'? I just tested it on JSFiddle and it works. [Click here to test it](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/988792/). I got the result `Object { symbol: "GOOG", companyName: "Alphabet Inc.", open: 1061.75, close: 1036.58, high: 1075.26, low: 1028.5, change: -32.15, changePercent: -0.03008 }`

Comment: What’s the exact error message that the browser logs in the devtools console?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/GOOG/quote?filter=symbol,companyName,open,close,high,low,change,changePercent. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/de753vtL/3/ It works in the callback for me.

Comment: @MaryB. Which browser (and version) are you using? Also it is worth trying to disable all your browser plugins/extensions and then see if it works.

Comment: The latest chrome and Firefox browsers @Ivar - but I would be surprised if this is a browser issue as when I issue the XMLHttp request outside of any function it works great with no errors — only when I insert any or all of the request and callbacks within the onSubmit() callback function for my input button do I get the CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a fix, and it has something to do with bubbling. It wasn't anywhere I was focused (namely, in my javascript file).  I still don't understand why I would get this CORS error.  If someone could chime in with a reason, I surely would appreciate it.

The error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/quote?filter=symbol,companyName,open,close,high,low,change,changePercent. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

The fix was to remove the form elements surrounding my Add button:

```
<body>
    <h1 ><center>Stock Watcher</center></h1> 
    <div id="root">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <form>
                 <input id="symbol" type="text" placeholder="Enter stock symbol...">
                 <button id="btn">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <script src="js/httpRequest.js"></script>
</body>
```